# Receiving: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, odbc

I recently "inherited" a VB project to convert it to Java, but first to debug it and find out why it stopped 2 months ago. Along with it I got several other projects. The problem is that when trying to open the connection I receive this error:

> [IM002][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and
>   no default driver specified

I know that it has been asked again but there is a twist: all the other projects that I got use the same `ConnectString` and they are working just fine, only this specific project has trouble opening the connection. Also the connection is on a server and the `ConnectString` contains the db's remote ip. I tried copying the Connection String from one project to the other, just in case, but the result was the same. I use VS 2013 and I am not too familiar with it yet, so please be as elaborate as possible.

So, what can cause the problem and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And "all the other projects" are on same machine as failing one?

Comment: And "all the other projects" use the same architecture - 32bit / 64bit - as the one that fails?